# Active directory server set up DNS resolution failure or VERY SLOW, can I route external DNS requests the traditional way, before the server existed?

Tags: dns, samba, active-directory, file-server

I'm very new to the world of active directory, windows server etc., so I apologise if some of the questions I ask are a bit stupid, but I'll try and explain exactly what I want to do below, and my currrent setup.

I'm running Ubuntu Server on a Raspberry Pi, using kerberos and other software detailed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgBuvA6J-_8) to use it as an AD-DC for my four clients that connect to it. At the moment this is really a test network on my Pi 2, before I launch on my Pi 4. The Raspbrry Pi is only just powerful enough to run the network and authenticate user logons and manage group policy etc, but DNS resolutions are extremely slow.

From the client perspective, the network is operating completely fine with logons and policy etc. EXCEPT what they have noticed is the time it takes to make a quick google search has increased dramatically and sometimes the search even fails.

Now, here's the question... **is there a way to operate my AD-DC server setup to manage group policy, users, groups, logon etc. *without* sending external DNS requests e.g. bbc.co.uk or google.com via the AD-DC. I want them to be processed as they would have before the server came along (by the router??) simply because it can't handle them, and the setup before the server was perfectly fine at handling them**

The windows clients are configured in dns settings to use the ADDC as their preferred dns server (if I change this, then they lose connection to the domain and can't find it...) and use 8.8.8.8 google's dns server as their secondary one, but whether I enter this in or not doesn't really seem to have an effect.

And if the ADDC server is down, ALL external dns requests across the entire network fail. It's like the backup isn't even there. You can't get onto google from a client when the DC is down.

Any info I'm happy to provide.

Secondary bonus question wondering why samba network transfer speed is dramatically slower using AD on this rapsberry pi rather than just installing samba and having it as a network share. Gone from 30Mb/s to 2Mb/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The windows clients are configured in dns settings to use the ADDC as their preferred dns server (if I change this, then they lose connection to the domain and can't find it...) and use 8.8.8.8 google's dns server as their secondary one

That's an invalid configuration, prone to unexpected errors in the Active Directory context. In an AD environment your (Windows) clients *must not* use a DNS server that doesn't know about your internal AD setup.

> Is there a way to operate my AD-DC server setup to manage group policy, users, groups, logon etc. without sending external DNS requests e.g. bbc.co.uk or google.com via the AD-DC

The Domain Controller for Active Directory must be canonical for your DNS domain. If you're asking whether you can have clients that don't use the DC for external DNS requests, then the answer is a qualified yes.

1. All DNS requests for your AD-controlled DNS domain *must* go to a DC
2. DNS requests for somewhere else may be resolved by any suitably responsive DNS server
3. You must not send DNS requests for your internal AD-controlled domain to an external server because its "NXDOMAIN" response will cause breakage

In the case of #2 for a Linux-based or other UNIX system *clients* you can use either `systemd` or `dnsmasq` to implement the stateful selection. (I've done both in various cases previously.)

- `systemd`

  Create `/etc/systemd/network/20-local.network`, setting the DNS server to be your AD DC, and your local domain as appropriate, remembering the leading `~`:

  ```
  # Network interface name (*=any)
  [Match]
  Name=*

  # Specific DNS server(s) to use for this domain
  [Network]
  DNS=10.0.0.1
  Domains=~contoso.com
  ```

  Create `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/20-local.conf`, setting the default external DNS servers as appropriate:

  ```
  [Resolve]
  DNS=1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9
  ```

  Reload the network and check the resolver

  ```
  systemctl restart systemd-networkd
  resolvectl status
  ```

  You should see that queries for your AD-controlled domain go to your Domain Controller, and everything else goes to 1.1.1.1 and/or 9.9.9.9.
- `dnsmasq.conf`

  Edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` setting the following values appropriately:

  ```
  # Global nameservers
  server=1.1.1.1
  server=9.9.9.9

  # Domain-specific nameserver (forward and reverse)
  server=/contoso.com/10.0.0.1
  server=/1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa/10.0.0.1
  ```

  Restart `dnsmasq`

---

Potentially useful references

- [How to configure the network interfaces](https://wiki.dave.eu/index.php?title=How_to_configure_the_network_interfaces) from Dave Embedded Systems
- [Configure systemd-resolved to use a specific DNS nameserver for a given domain](https://gist.github.com/brasey/fa2277a6d7242cdf4e4b7c720d42b567) from Gist (Github)
- [Need to set different DNS configurations for home and work](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/need-to-set-different-dns-configurations-for-home-and-work/86830) from Ask Fedora
- [domain-based routing with systemd-resolved](https://superuser.com/q/1687861/332907) from SuperUser

Comment: Wow, seriously helpful answer you've understood exactly what I'm getting at. Sorry for the lack of experience or basic knowledge when I'm tackling such a thing. I'll give it a go now, should I remove the secondary 'alternative dns server' option being 8.8.8.8 on the windows clients? Thanks for this @Chris Davies

Comment: Can I also ask what happens if the DC is down/offline? Users that have logged into that particular client computer in the past will be allowed to log on, obviously network shares won't be available, but will external DNS requests still be handled? E.g. as they would have been before the whole domain existed i.e externally?

Comment: And finally sorry, am I leaving "[Match] Name=enxb827eb315364" as that string, or have I got a name to enter there?

Comment: I have followed your instructions exactly and get to the point where I am checking the resolvectl status and i get the response 'failed to get global data: unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found;

Comment: You are doing these changes on clients and not on your AD DC server, aren't you. It sounds like they're not using systemd's resolver. You can start it with `systemctl start systemd-resolved` but I would double-check how DNS resolving is happening on these clients before you make these changes

Comment: "_you've understood exactly what I'm getting at_" - I've been running mixed networks for over 10 years in an international organisation that needed local DNS resiliency in the event that the central DCs were unavailable

Comment: @OliverRicketts I've updated the `[Match`] stanza to use a wildcard - much easier than enumerating the interface name for each client

Comment: Sorry, no I misunderstood. How can I make the changes on clients. They're running Win11 Pro. All the clients are, I should've been clearer sorry.

Comment: In that case you can't make these changes, because they're only for Linux/UNIX client. Except that none of the (Windows) clients must use any DNS server other than the AD DC

Comment: Sorry I've made this a bit confusing. Here's where I'm at now, and I understand it more so am able to word it simpler. On the windows client, following the video I linked's instructions, you set the 'default gateway' to your dc's ip address (in my case 192.168.1.153). This means that external requests e.g. to access google.com are going through the dc. If I change the gateway BACK to my router's ip (192.168.1.254) which it was before the domain came along, then the resolving issue completely disappears, sites load in seconds. BUT, the domain can't be found. Loses the entire domain....

Comment: Default gateway is totally different to DNS. Do not set the default gateway to the DC - that would be strange. DNS = DC, Gateway = Router

Comment: It's almost like I need two gateways, the router to handle external requests (254) and the dc (153) to handle requests on the network e.g. logon authentication. **If I make the default gateway for the client my router, the resolution issues clear, but the domain is lost, policy not applied, domain.local can't even be pinged from the client..... AND if I make the dc the default gateway on the client, simple searches online from the client won't resolve. I get a loading screen before failure.**

Comment: I've just realised that this (default gateway) is now the issue rather than dns settings. Should I make a new question and rephrase the problem, or do you think you know a solution?

Comment: Sorry to mess you around, I'm fairly new and young (just turned 18!) to tech like this, especially IT forums, and especially domains.

Comment: Are your clients and the AD DC on the same subnet? If so you shouldn't need to use the DC as your default gateway

Comment: Yes, same subnet mask. The win11 clients only seem to recognise the domain (domain.local) as something that exists when the default gateway is set to the DC.

Comment: I've re-uploaded a question now I've realised what I actually need help with. If you have any ideas I'd greatly appreciate, but thanks so much for your help and time here. [Here's the new post.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/760577/active-directory-server-default-gateway-resolution-issues)