# Active directory server default gateway resolution issues

Tags: dns, active-directory, kerberos, domain, gateway

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu Server acting as an active directory domain controller with samba and kerberos etc as detailed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgBuvA6J-_8). I have three Windows 11 Professional clients part of the domain. The clients are configured with their own IP address, use the same network-wide subnet mask, and dns settings are routed to the dc, with the secondary (alternative dns server) as the default wifi router (as a device off the network domain would use).

In the video, it shows changing the default gateway of the windows clients to the IP address of the DC. I made this change, and connected to the domain successfully. However, when performing basic searches or accessing external sites online on the clients, it is EXTREMELY SLOW or fails to load even the simplest page.

If I change the default gateway of the client back to the router IP address (as it would have been originally), then the webpages load completely fine, however, the client loses the domain entirely, and doesn't even recognise it as existing. E.g. a ping to exampledomain.local doesn't reach.

**Is there a way to remain part of the domain, in touch with the DC, whilst using the gateway of the router on the clients?**

Very new to all this, including IT forums etc, so feedback on my question appreciated.

Comment: "changing the default gateway of the windows clients to the IP address of the DC"... I've been administrating AD for close to a decade now, I've never heard of this. A DC is not an open relay/proxy by default.

Comment: Just to be clear: you did join the clients to the domain, right? If you're using the DC as DNS, it *should* be able to resolve the domain.

Comment: To add to the previous comment: if your DC cannot resolve the domain, it seems that your DNS setup on the DC is broken (refer to your previous question).

Comment: @Panki have I confused myself? 29m into the video linked in the question, I don't understand what he's put into default gateway. Could you also explain why the client can't find the entire domain if I leave the gateway as the standard default (the router)?

Comment: This is a follow-on from [Active directory server set up DNS resolution failure or VERY SLOW, can I route external DNS requests the traditional way, before the server existed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/760527/100397)

Comment: You should be using your router's network for all your machines. For example 192.168.0.0/24. The video complicates things at that point. Do not use his invented 10.0.0.0/n network. The clients can continue to use DHCP. The server must have a static (fixed) IP address

Comment: @ChrisDavies I've fixed it. Thanks for all your help throughout the whole thing and huge apologies for my incompetence

Comment: Excellent news. Please take the time to post an answer to your own question here. That way others can benefit from your learning experience. (Don't consider it incompetence - it might be a mistake, but how else would you have learnt?)